# change values periodically in a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe

Assume I have a data frame of the form

```
index         names
1             Gina
2             George
3             John
4             Alex
5   
6
7
8
9             Nathan
10
11
12
13
14            Alice
15
16
17
18
```

And I want to transform it like this

```
index         names
1             Gina
2             George
3             John
4             Alex
5             Alex
6             Alex
7             Alex
8             Alex
9             Alex
10            Nathan
11            Nathan
12            Nathan
13            Nathan
14            Alice
15            Alice
16            Alice
17            Alice
18            Alice
```

Basically i have to copy paste the value in the index 4 times. What i have done is to create a list

```
for i in range(4,100,5):
loop.append(i)
```

In which i will have the values where my name i need to copy is each time and then i was thinking of creating a simple loop in the form

```
for i in loop:
  name1[i+1,0]= name1[i,0]
  name1[i+2,0]= name1[i,0]
  name1[i+3,0]= name1[i,0]
  name1[i+4,0]= name1[i,0]
```

But i get an error in the form of

```
 File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 109, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
KeyError: (3, 0)
```

EDIT : Because perhaps I was not very clear. I have a data frame with empty values. As you can see my value at the index 4 is Alex, at index 9 is Nathan and at index 14 is Alice. I want to copy paste that value to the next 4 rows. That is happening periodically. So i create a list where i have the index of the name I want to copy [4,9,14,19,24,...,95] and then a loop to copy the name from the index to the next 4 rows

Answer (score 0):

I think the you are trying to achieve pandas equivalent of`ffill`. Try using the following code:

```py
c = ['names']
df.loc[:,c] = df.loc[:,c].ffill()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get your question either, but even simplier than @oreopot answer:

```
df['name'] = df['name'].ffill()
```

Comment: Take a look here: [link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: i tried name1.fillna(method='ffill') but it doesn t do anything if the elements are empty. If they are nan they still remain nan. Also i tried #name1['names'] = name1['names'].ffill(inplace=True ) and it fills everything with none

Comment: Be aware that if you use inplace=True you are already changin the content of the caller (in this case name1['names']), so thats why you get None, because that sentence returns None.
Use `name1['names'] = name1['names'].ffill()` or `name1['names'].ffill(inplace=True)`